# Is it right to post false details in one's user profile?

Tags: discussion, support

In AU there seems to be a badge for completing one's user profile. But when I visited a few profiles it seemed to me that they have false details. I mean they have every right to not post their details..but false details? And one gets a badge for giving false details! That seems wrong to me!(Well, morally) One might especially see false website addresses, sometimes places etc. . So by AU rules is this right? If it is, doesn't this largely bring down the value of a badge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh, come on! First of all, there is absolutely no value in the badges anyway. These are just useless internet points people! Then, I can write whatever I like in my profile. If I want to say I am a small green creature from a planet orbiting Alpha Centauri, I can. There is nothing morally wrong here, that's why SE is anonymous. You can, if you choose, use your real name and give real information and you can, if you wish, create a fictitious persona. Nothing wrong with that.

For example, my "Real Name" in my profile is simply Greek for "I won't tell you". Obviously, that's not my real name and I have absolutely no desire to give my real name out  on the internet. Why should I?

So, in conclusion, people are free to write whatever they like in their profiles. Apart from my name, everything I have there happens to be true but this is not a government registration site, it's just a site for Ubuntu geeks and we are under no obligation to provide true details.

Comment: Where do we get to see your "real name"?

Comment: @guntbert you don't, I think it is only visible to you and probably  the mods. Check your own profile, there is a Real Name field.

Comment: I know I have it in my own profile - your wording seemed to imply that it is there for everybody to see.

Comment: Besides, how do we prove you aren't 200 and from alpha centauri?